# Bug in TextField in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

When I tap on Text Field and write from keyboard then I click done,
all data from Text Field was cleared.
This is my code:

```dart
TextField(
  controller: controller,
  keyboardType: textInputType,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: hintText,
    enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5),
    ),
    focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.black,
        width: 1,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

my controller:
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

Comment: Can you show what you have put in your controller ?

Comment: apart from showing what you put in your controller, mind explain or show what your "click done" function means?

Comment: i mean with done when i finish insert text in Text Field

Comment: TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a stateless widget, and you're instantiating the TextEditingController in it. Closing the keyboard is causing a rebuild and you're losing the state, and a new controller is being created. You'll want to use a stateful widget and put the TextEditingController in state.